# Where does the source code for chart comes from ... it is not mentioned here clearly but output occurs..?

Tags: angular

Where does the data from trading view chart come from in angular? We are just describing the css and styles of the elements used.. but source of data was not mentioned there ...?

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    new TradingView.widget({
       'container_id': 'technical-analysis',
       'autosize': true,
      //  'symbol': this.symbolPair,
       'interval': '120',
       'timezone': 'exchange',
       'theme': 'Dark',
       'style': '1',
       'toolbar_bg': '#f1f3f6',
       'withdateranges': true,
       'hide_side_toolbar': false,
       'allow_symbol_change': true,
       'save_image': false,
       'hideideas': true,
       'studies': [ 
       'MASimple@tv-basicstudies' ],
       'show_popup_button': true,
       'popup_width': '1000',
       'popup_height': '650'
     });
   }
}
declare const TradingView: any;
```

index.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
```

I got output but Data source was not mentioned here